# Is it possible to mirror my app(Android) so that i can view it on tv via chromecast?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am new to Chromecast and tried to run few tutorials like adding cast button and connecting my app with TV.

I made an app in android and i want to show it on tv via chromecast so that i should control it via phone and app features run on tv.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @GB_Bhayani Currently,I am running demo projects on a projector through HDMI port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot mirror your phone's screen to TV using the official chromecast SDK.

Comment: But before that is giving me one problem . Whenever i run my app i am getting a login window(username and password) . I have another app id that i picked from google cast tuorials, it is giving me output as expected. Kindly help